# Error doing Oauth2 token POST request with JWT in Node.js "internal error" "unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---..."

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, token

I am a beginner to Node and am trying to create a microservice to route API calls between google's Dialogflow and a company backend server. I believe that in order to make API calls to edit intents etc I need an Oauth2 access token but I am stuck trying to acquire the token.

I have seen this error posted before here: [Unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data in google plus api oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107881/unsupported-content-with-type-multipart-form-data-in-google-plus-api-oauth2)

BUT none of those answers were working (for me at least) and it's 2 years old so thought it was worth making a fresh post.

I am currently using the following jwt-generator.js from https://www.jwt.io to create a JWT:

```js
// Using CryptoJS library
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")

// Defining our token parts
var header = {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
  };
  
  var claimSet = {
    "iss": "dialogflow-iprbag@PROJETID.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope": "google.cloud.dialogflow/",
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp": Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + 3600,
    "iat": Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)
  };
  
  var secret = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----blahblahblah-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  
  function base64url(source) {
    // Encode in classical base64
    encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);
    
    // Remove padding equal characters
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');
    
    // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');
    
    return encodedSource;
  }
  
  var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
  var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);
  
  var stringifiedClaimSet = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(claimSet));
  var encodedClaimSet = base64url(stringifiedClaimSet);
  
  var signature = stringifiedHeader + "." + stringifiedClaimSet;
  signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, secret);
  signature = base64url(signature);
  
  console.log(encodedHeader + "." + encodedClaimSet + "." + signature);
```

I am then sending the generated JWT to the Oauth2 token server in a POST request with the following token-get.js node script:

```js
const request = require('request')

var formData = {
    "grant_type": "urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer",
    "assertion": JWT_HERE,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

request.post({url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', formData: formData}, function(req, err, res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

It is my understanding that the grant_type header is constant but when I test this request in postman I get an invalid grant_type error. When I run the token-get.js I get an unsupported dataForm error.

Honestly I am quite lost and there seems to be no good source for help on this topic that suits my application. If anyone is experienced in this topic please let me know!

Thanks